# We found a problem with some content in (filename.xlsm)

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I tried to open a xlsm file, I keep getting a "We found a problem with some content with filename.xlsm. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes"

I did click yes, and some things were removed, and when I opened the xml file, I found this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error183640_01.xml</logFileName>
<summary>Errors were detected in file 'filepath'</summary>
-<repairedParts>
<repairedPart xml:space="preserve">Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part. </repairedPart>
</repairedParts>
</recoveryLog>
```

What was supposed to be there when I open the file is some list data validation on the three yellow boxes, and the macros with the shortcut keys as listed in the other columns. But upon opening the VBA, the sheet just disappears, and the macro moves to another sheet.

I'm at the end of my rope trying this out. I wish I can attach my file to show you guys, but I don't know how to as I am a new user here. I'll just use an image

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Kind Regards,
Jonathan Handojo

Comment: Your file is corrupted - best you can do is either go back to a "known good" version, or try to fix the broken file.

Comment: I believe it's something to do with my macros. I think that's what's causing the error. I've tried doing from scratch again, typed the macros again from scratch, and the same problem persist. It didn't show up when I didn't run any one of my macros. I'll just have to find it one by one until I find it. One of it is worksheet_change, and another 6 listing the ones above.